# How do I sort a collection of Lists in lexicographic order in Scala?

Tags: sorting, scala, html-lists, lexicographic

If `A` has the `Ordered[A]` trait, I'd like to be able to have code that works like this

```
val collection: List[List[A]] = ... // construct a list of lists of As
val sorted = collection sort { _ < _ }
```

and get something where the lists have been sorted in lexicographic order. Of course, just because `A` has the trait `Ordered[A]` doesn't mean that `List[A]` has the trait `Ordered[List[A]]`. Presumably, however, the 'scala way' to do this is with an implicit def.

**How do I implicitly convert a `List[A]` to a `Ordered[List[A]]`, assuming A has the trait `Ordered[A]` (so that the code above just works)?**

I have in mind using the lexicographic ordering on `List[A]` objects, but I'd like code that can be adapted to others orderings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by Ben Lings' answer, I wrote my own version of `sort`:

```
def sort[A : Ordering](coll: Seq[Iterable[A]]) = coll.sorted
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def sort[A](coll: Seq[Iterable[A]])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]) = coll.sorted
```

Note that `ordering` is implicitly converted to `Ordering[Iterable[A]]`.

Examples:

```
scala> def sort[A](coll: Seq[Iterable[A]])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]) = coll.sorted
sort: [A](coll: Seq[Iterable[A]])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A])Seq[Iterable[A]]

scala> val coll = List(List(1, 3), List(1, 2), List(0), Nil, List(2))
coll: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 3), List(1, 2), List(0), List(), List(2))

scala> sort(coll)
res1: Seq[Iterable[Int]] = List(List(), List(0), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(2))
```

It was asked how to supply your own comparison function (say, `_ > _` instead of `_ < _`). It suffices to use `Ordering.fromLessThan`:

```
scala> sort(coll)(Ordering.fromLessThan(_ > _))
res4: Seq[Iterable[Int]] = List(List(), List(2), List(1, 3), List(1, 2), List(0))
```

`Ordering.by` allows you to map your value into another type for which there is already an Ordering instance. Given that also tuples are ordered, this can be useful for lexicographical comparison of case classes.

To make an example, let's define a wrapper of an Int, apply `Ordering.by(_.v)`, where `_.v` extracts the underlying value, and show that we obtain the same result:

```
scala> case class Wrap(v: Int)
defined class Wrap

scala> val coll2 = coll.map(_.map(Wrap(_)))
coll2: List[List[Wrap]] = List(List(Wrap(1), Wrap(3)), List(Wrap(1), Wrap(2)), List(Wrap(0)), List(), List(Wrap(2)))

scala> sort(coll2)(Ordering.by(_.v))
res6: Seq[Iterable[Wrap]] = List(List(), List(Wrap(0)), List(Wrap(1), Wrap(2)), List(Wrap(1), Wrap(3)), List(Wrap(2)))
```

Finally, let's do the same thing on a case class with more members, reusing the comparators for Tuples:

```
scala> case class MyPair(a: Int, b: Int)
defined class MyPair

scala> val coll3 = coll.map(_.map(MyPair(_, 0)))
coll3: List[List[MyPair]] = List(List(MyPair(1,0), MyPair(3,0)), List(MyPair(1,0), MyPair(2,0)), List(MyPair(0,0)), List(), List(MyPair(2,0)))

scala> sort(coll3)(Ordering.by(x => (x.a, x.b)))
res7: Seq[Iterable[MyPair]] = List(List(), List(MyPair(0,0)), List(MyPair(1,0), MyPair(2,0)), List(MyPair(1,0), MyPair(3,0)), List(MyPair(2,0)))
```

EDIT:

My definition of `sort` above is deprecated in 2.13:

```
warning: method Iterable in object Ordering is deprecated (since 2.13.0):
Iterables are not guaranteed to have a consistent order; if using a type
with a consistent order (e.g. Seq), use its Ordering (found in the
Ordering.Implicits object)
```

Use instead:

```
def sort[A](coll: Seq[Seq[A]])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]) = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._
  coll.sorted
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Inspired by Ben Lings' answer, I managed to work out what seems like the simplest way to sort lists lexicographically: add the line

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
```

before doing your List[Int] comparison, to ensure that the implicit function `infixOrderingOps` is in scope.

Comment: thanks, this is a great solution. Happily, I'm able to switch immediately to 2.9.

Answer (score 6):

(11 minutes ago I actually didn't know how to do this, I hope it's considered okay to answer my own question.)

```
implicit def List2OrderedList[A <% Ordered[A]](list1: List[A]): Ordered[List[A]] = { 
    new Ordered[List[A]] {
        def compare(list2: List[A]): Int = {
            for((x,y) <- list1 zip list2) {
                val c = x compare y
                if(c != 0) return c
            }
            return list1.size - list2.size
        }
    }
}
```

An important thing to note here is the '[view bound](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130)' `A <% Ordered[A]`, which ensures that `A` needn't itself by an `Ordered[A]`, just that there's a way to do this conversion. Happily, the Scala library's object `Predef` has an implicit conversion from `Int`s to `RichInt`s, which in particular are `Ordered[Int]`s.

The rest of the code is just implementing lexicographic ordering.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather use a recursive algorithm, which can be made tail-recursive for this particular problem.

Comment: @Daniel, could you briefly explain why you'd rather use a recursive algorithm?

Comment: Lists lead themselves to recursive algorithms quite easily, so I'm used to think of recursion with them. And, in this case, I think it would be cleaner. Still, it's purely a matter of taste and style.

Comment: Not sure why, but my recursive version seems to be faster.

Answer (score 4):

In 2.8, you should be able to just do `collection.sorted`. `sorted` takes an implicit `Ordering` parameter.  Any type that implements `Ordered` has a corresponding `Ordering` (thanks to the implicit conversion `Ordering.ordered`).  There is also the implicit `Ordering.Iterable` that makes an `Iterable[T]` have an `Ordering` if `T` has an `Ordering`.

However, if you try this it doesn't work:

```
scala> def sort[A <: Ordered[A]](coll: List[List[A]]) = coll.sorted

<console>:5: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ord: Ordering[List[A]]
       def sort[A <: Ordered[A]](coll: List[List[A]]) = coll.sorted
                                                             ^
```

You need to explicitly specify that you want the `Ordering[Iterable[A]]`:

```
def sort[A <: Ordered[A]](coll: List[List[A]]) = coll.sorted[Iterable[A]]
```

I'm not sure why the compiler can't find the `Ordering[Iterable[A]]` if the element type of the collection is `List[A]`.

Comment: Not sure that answers the question since you can't pass a comparison function. Also, oddly calling your sort function on a `List(List(1),Nil)` will cause an `inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method sort's type parameter bounds [A <: Ordered[A]]`. But sorted does work on a literal: `List(List(1), Nil).sorted[Iterable[Int]]`.

Comment: The Ordering object has several utility methods to supply your own functions.
Ordering.fromLessThan allows you to transform your own comparison function into an Ordering instance. Ordering.by() allows you to map your value into another type which _already_ for which there is already an Ordering instance.
Ordering is not covariant (because of the signature of max); therefore, Ordering[List[A]] and Ordering[Iterable[A]] are incompatible. sorted allows "upcasting" the element type, but for some reason type inference can't figure this out.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the above sort requires to extend Ordered, and that's too restrictive. Will post an altered answer.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Daniel's comment, here is a recursive version:

```
implicit def toOrdered[A <% Ordered[A]](list1: List[A]): Ordered[List[A]] = { 
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def c(list1:List[A], list2:List[A]): Int = {
    (list1, list2) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => 0
      case (x::xs, Nil) => 1
      case (Nil, y::ys) => -1
      case (x::xs, y::ys) => (x compare y) match {
        case 0 => c(xs, ys)
        case i => i
      }
    }
  }
  new Ordered[List[A]] {
    def compare(list2: List[A]): Int = c(list1, list2)
  }
}
```

With respect to the comment:
I used to think it's more a matter of taste. Sometimes it's easier to verify correctness on a recursive function, and certainly your version is short enough that there is no compelling reason to prefer recursive.

I was intrigued by the performance implications though. So I tried to benchmark it: see http://gist.github.com/468435. I was surprised to see that the recursive version is faster (assuming I did the benchmark correctly). The results still hold true for list of about length 10.

Comment: Thanks @huynhjl. I'm curious though --- what's the advantage of the recursive version here? I love recursion when it makes life easy, but I'm missing the point here.

Comment: zip builds a new, zipped list. Probably using list1.view.zipView(list2) could solve this problem, but maybe it would still be slow because of the indirection due to using views.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I already implemented this another way, here is a non-recursive version that does not use `return`:

```scala
new Ordering[Seq[String]]() {
  override def compare(x: Seq[String], y: Seq[String]): Int = {
    x.zip(y).foldLeft(None: Option[Int]){ case (r, (v, w)) =>
        if(r.isDefined){
          r
        } else {
          val comp = v.compareTo(w)
          if(comp == 0) None
          else Some(comp)
        }
      }.getOrElse(x.size.compareTo(y.size))
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can replace
`        if(r.isDefined){
          r
        } else { ...
`
with `r orElse {...`