# Ordering for a Seq[String] in a more functional manner

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given an `Ordering[Seq[String]` like this:

```scala
new Ordering[Seq[String]]() {
  override def compare(x: Seq[String], y: Seq[String]): Int = {
    var i = 0
    while (i < Math.min(x.size, y.size)) {
      val c = x(i).compareTo(y(i))
      if (c != 0) return c
      i += 1
    }
    Integer.compare(x.size, y.size)
  }
}
```

This sorts a `Seq[Seq[String]]` according to the first `String` that differs from the comparing sequence - or according to the sequences size if there are no differing `String`s.

While this implementation works well, I would like to have an implementation without any `var`s or `return`s but cannot wrap my head around how to implement such a (more functional) ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [an older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490865/14955), lexicographic ordering of sequences of sequences is already provided by a standard implicit:

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
Seq(
  Seq("a", "c"),
  Seq("a", "b"),
  Seq("a")
).sorted
// => List(List(a), List(a, b), List(a, c))
```

Comment: That linked thread also has a couple of `Ordering[Seq]` implementations if you want to do it yourself (maybe to tweak how exactly it works).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Didn't see the other thread before.